# How to know if an international bond fund is currency hedged

Tags: bonds, foreign-exchange, international, bond-funds

I want to invest in only international bond funds that are currency hedged.

How can I find out if a fund is currency hedged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ETF will have it in its name already.

Otherwise it will be adressed in the fund prospectus. Also the fund hedge rate will be adressed (you do not have to hedge 100% of the currency risk).

Yet another way could be the top holdings which should be in the fact sheet. If you have forex stuff in there its likely hedged.